# Prove that every continuous map $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ has a fixed point.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Prove that every continuous map $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ has a fixed point.

Suppose $f$ does not have a fixed point, then $\forall x \in [0,1], f(x) \neq x$.

Thus we have a well defined function $g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)-x}$. Note that as $g(x)$ is the composition or continuous functions, it must be continuous.

However, $g(0) > 0$ and $g(1) < 0$, so by the intermediate value theorem $\exists x \in [0,1]$ such that $g(x) = 0$. This is clearly impossible.

Thus $f$ has a fixed point.

Comment: This is correct but it is simpler to use $g(x)=f(x)-x$.

Comment: I guess the proof is okay, but in my opinion it's not natural. The natural g to define is $g(x)=f(x)-x;$ can you see the geometrical motivation behind defining this function ?

Comment: Well. If we replace continuous with increment, is the proposition still valid?

Comment: This is special case of Schauder's fixed point theorem: any continuous $f:K\to K$ has a fixed point where $K$ is a compact convex subset of a Banach space (for example, of $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @Starlight237 Yes, if $f$ is increasing, this follows from Tarski's fixed point theorem, which says that if $f:L\to L$ is increasing where $L$ is a complete lattice, then fixed points of $f$ also form a complete lattice, in particular there's at least one fixed point of $f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Anyway note that the function $f$ must meet the line $y=x$ in atleast one point, and that point is the fixed point. To see this geometrical idea into a formal proof, set $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and apply IVT to $g$.