# Difficult to understand why Brouwer's fixed-point theorem holds

Tags: calculus, fixed-point-theorems

I am asked to prove or give a counterexample to the following statement:

> If $f$ is continuous on the interval $[0, 1]$ and if $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ for every $x \in [0, 1]$, then
> there exists a point $c \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(c) = c$.

I have difficulty understanding the solution which agrees with the statement, since for example if we have $f(x) = 0.5$, this function seems to match every condition?

Comment: What have you done to prove or give a counterexample?

Comment: $f(x) = 1/2$ has fixed point $c = 1/2$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): share your work (and [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that every continuous map $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ has a fixed point.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271176/prove-that-every-continuous-map-f-0-1-rightarrow-0-1-has-a-fixed-point)

Comment: Hint: try to plot the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and try to plot a graph of an arbitrary function with the required properties. Try to plot the diagonal (i.e. the graph of the function $y(x)=x$). Your function will necessarily cross the diagonal line at least in a point.  I think that then you can use the intermediate value theorem to formalize the idea.

Answer (score 0):

To respond directly to your proposed wonder:

> I have difficulty understanding the solution which agrees with the statement, since for example if we have $f(x)=0.5$, this function seems to match every condition?

If you have a function $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$ and defined by $x \mapsto 0.5$, then there *is* a point $c \in [0,1]$ with the desired property. In particular, consider $c = 0.5$. Then, you have $f(c) = c$ since $f(0.5) = 0.5$.

This means that your example is not a counterexample.